# Valid GitHub acct but GitHub Extension for Visual studio 2017 show validation failed

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, github-for-windows

I have created a GitHub acct. I can use browser to login to this acct.
However, when I used the same credential on Visual studio 2017 with Git Extension in stalled to sign in , I got the below message:

Validation failed

How to resolve this issue. Is there anyone experienced the same issue as my?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you are using? Have you try to update the Visual Studio to the latest version and reinstall that extension or run VS as administrator? It works fine on my side.

Answer (score 0):

If you click "Sign in with your browser" under the Connect To GitHub window from the VS Team Explorer, do you make sure that you could sign in your browser？

I create a new GitHub acct, I get the same result as yours (Validation failed)in my side if I use that extension in my VS, but if I visit it in browser, I will get the following result if I select the "Sign in with your browser" option.

But if your account was verified, it will work well after you create a new repository. I test it in my side, it works normally now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MilkBottle, Would you please share the latest information in your side? If the reply is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer. So we could close this case for you, if not, feel free to share the latest information in your side.